# I wrote the rest api but body is return nil in golang . Why returning "0 {<nil> false [] <nil> false 0 <nil> 0}"

Tags: go, jira-rest-api

```
func InsertApData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    fmt.Printf("Request Body : ", decoder)
    var apdata models.ApData
    err := decoder.Decode(&apdata)
    check(b.E(err))
    _, err2 := stmt.InsertApData.Exec(apdata.Mac, apdata.RssiMax, apdata.RssiMin, apdata.LocDefId)
    check(b.E(err2))
}
```

and data type for db

```
type ApData struct {
    ID       int    `db:"id"`
    Mac      string `db:"mac"`
    RssiMax  uint64 `db:"rssi_max"`
    RssiMin  uint16 `db:"rssi_min"`
    LocDefId uint64 `db:"loc_def_id"`
}
```

Why returning

> Request Body : %!(EXTRA *json.Decoder=&{0xc820012b00 [] {[] 0 {
>   false []  false 0  0} { false []  false 0  0}
>    false} 0 { false []  false 0  0}  0 []})

also json :

```
{
"mac":"01:0a:95:9d:68:20",
"rssi_max":-73.50,
"rssi_min":-50.02,
"loc_def_id":1
}
```

Comment: There is no format specifier (e.g. `%d`) in the `fmt.Printf` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the source code for `json.Decoder`,

```
...
type Decoder struct {
    r     io.Reader
    buf   []byte
    d     decodeState
    scanp int // start of unread data in buf
    scan  scanner
    err   error

    tokenState int
    tokenStack []int
}

func NewDecoder(r io.Reader) *Decoder {
    return &Decoder{r: r}
}
...
```

you can see that `NewDecoder` only sets the `r` field, and that is what you are observing in the output of `fmt.Printf`.

Until you execute `err := decoder.Decode(&apdata)`, your structure will not be filled in. What you are seeing in the output is the content of the decoder, not the body or your structure.

If you print your structure after running `err := decoder.Decode(&apdata)`, it contains proper data:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    input := `{
        "mac":"01:0a:95:9d:68:20",
        "rssi_max":-73.50,
        "rssi_min":-50.02,
        "loc_def_id":1
    }`

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input))
    var apdata struct {
            ID       int    `db:"id"`
            Mac      string `json:"mac" db:"mac"`
            RssiMax  uint64 `json:"rssi_max" db:"rssi_max"`
            RssiMin  uint16 `json:"rssi_min" db:"rssi_min"`
            LocDefId uint64 `json:"loc_def_id" db:"loc_def_id"`
    }
    _ = decoder.Decode(&apdata)
    fmt.Printf("appdata : %+v\n", apdata)
}
```

Output:

```
appdata : {ID:0 Mac:01:0a:95:9d:68:20 RssiMax:0 RssiMin:0 LocDefId:1}
```

The `RssiMax` and `RssiMin` are zero because they are unsigned ints receiving negative values.

Comment: Thank you , I working on it . I'll get back to you on that subject

Comment: Hey ralph , thank you so much. I just forgot to add the Json model. :) Data has reached the db.